# Http error: 404 after Install JAI and JAI Image on GeoServer with export _POSIX2_VERSION=199209

Tags: geoserver, jai

I was installing JAI and JAI Image, when I follow the documentation from Geoserver, the JAI work ok, without problems, but when I install JAI Image with the commands, from jdk8 folder (location) as the documentation from geoserver:

```
$ export _POSIX2_VERSION=199209
$ sh jai_imageio-1_1-lib-linux-i586-jdk.bin
accept license_
```

the install is correct, but when i start Geoserver, it show the error message:

> *http error: 404  problem accessing /geoserver/.  reason: not found*

I can't access to Geoserver, i have to re install Java (Rollback), then the Geoserver working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are installing Java 6, any modern GeoServer requires Java 8 to run.

If that is not your problem then please add the contents of the GeoServer log file (or catalina.out) to see what is going wrong.

Comment: I correct it, java that i use is jdk 8 (java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: I checked the log, but no show nothing, may be i have set something more in the log?

Comment: how i add the log anyway?